# Sonarqube: grab tests from multiple directories AND avoid an 'file can't be indexed twice'

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**Answers to questions like 'how to grab tests from multile folders' and to questions 'how to avoid file can't be indexed twice' are just opposite each other. So this question is not a duplicate of one of them.**

I have a structure like that:

```
src
  |_component1
  |          |__tests__
  |                    |_units.tsx
  |
  |_component2
             |__tests__
                       |_units.tsx
```

If I try customize `sonar` like this:

```
'sonar.sources': 'src',
'sonar.tests': 'src',
'sonar.exclusions': 'src/**/__tests__/**/*',
'sonar.tests.inclusions': 'src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
```

It fails with error `file can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns produce disjoint sets for main and test files`.

If I provide `sonar.sources` and `sonar.tests` with different paths, it can't see my multiple `__tests__` directories.

How could I combine both grab multiple test directories and avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, I've got an answer!

Proper settings are:

```
'sonar.sources': 'src',
'sonar.tests': 'src',
'sonar.exclusions': '**/__tests__/**',
'sonar.test.inclusions': '**/__tests__/**',
```

It's not `sonar.TESTS.inclusions`, it's `sonar.TEST.inclusions`, 1 letter difference.